# Not able to Access DNN service on public IP

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I have created DNN service .
Its running on my localhost but i am not able to access on public IP.
I have done following steps:

1. Create Site on IIS and added path of my application
2. Added Port and open it on AWS public IP
3. Given all permission to my application folder.

I am getting this Error:

404 Not Found The requested Url does not return any valid content. Administrators Change this message by configuring a specific 404 Error Page or Url for this website.

Comment: Did you add the IP Address to the bindings in IIS

Answer (score 1):

Just I Added new entry in **PortalAlias** table and provide my Public ip with port as HTTPAlias.